# nginx downloads php files instead of executing them (HHVM)

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I'm trying to setup HHVM to execute my PHP code. I was using Apache, but I switched to nginx and I've almost got it working. However, when I try to access `index.php` it will download the file instead of execute/serve it. This is my configuration, and I ran `usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi` after configuring and subsequently restarted my nginx service.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I just had to include the `hhvm.conf` file, and do the `try_files` stuff. Here's my new configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    include hhvm.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
}
```